# Find all THs of a table row that has a header with child THs

Tags: jquery, html, html-table

I have a table that has a header which it has child header like below:

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th rowspan="2">Fisrt Name</th>
    <th rowspan="2">Last Name</th>
    <th colspan="4">Day 1</th>
    <th colspan="4">Day 2</th>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <th session-id="101">Session 1</th>
    <th session-id="102">Session 2</th>
    <th session-id="103">Session 3</th>
    <th session-id="104">Session 4</th>
    
    <th session-id="105">Session 1</th>
    <th session-id="106">Session 2</th>
    <th session-id="107">Session 3</th>
    <th session-id="108">Session 4</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td student-id="110">Foo</td>
    <td>Bar</td>
    
    <td>Present</td>
    <td>Absent</td>
    <td>Present</td>
    <td>Present</td>
    <td>Absent</td>
    <td>Present</td>
    <td>Present</td>
    <td>Present</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to get the attendance data for each student. I use this jQuery code to iterate over all columns of the table rows. the problem is some columns at the last are not considered.

```
 $('#attendanceTable tbody > tr')
    .each(function(i, row) {
        var studentId = '';
        var list = [];

        $(row)
            .find('td')
            .each(function(j, column) {
                if (j === 0) {
                    studentId = $(column).attr('student-id');
                } 
                else 
                {
                    // Each session tds has a session id
                    var $th = $(column).closest('table').find('th').eq($(column).index());
                    var sessionId = $th.attr('session-id');

                    if (sessionId){
                        list.push(sessionId);
                    }
                }
            });
        // do sth with list
        list = [];
    });
```

Each row has 10 columns, but when iterating by `$(row).find('td').each(function(j, column)` it iterates over this columns `[First name, Last Name, Day 1, Day 2, Session1-to-session4, SESSION1-to-SESSION2]` and problem raises here.

I think the below line causes the problem.

```
var $th = $(column).closest('table').find('th').eq($(column).index());
```

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: You want row with values e.g. Foo, Bar , absent, present?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `rowspan` attribute is messing up the calculations. You are also not considering the fact that the header cells are spread across two rows. You could refactor the code like this, and more importantly, simply subtract 2 from `.index()` to find the matching header:

```js
var $table = $("#attendanceTable");
var $headers = $table.find("thead > tr:nth-child(2) th");
$table.find("tbody > tr").each(function() {
  var studentId = $(this).find("td:nth-child(1)").attr("student-id");
  var list = [];
  /* td:nth-child(n+3) means third cell and onwards */
  $(this).find("td:nth-child(n+3)").each(function() {
    var $th = $headers.eq($(this).index() - 2);
    var sessionId = $th.attr("session-id");
    list.push(sessionId);
  });
  console.log(list);
});
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="attendanceTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="2">Fisrt Name</th>
      <th rowspan="2">Last Name</th>
      <th colspan="4">Day 1</th>
      <th colspan="4">Day 2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th session-id="101">Session 1</th>
      <th session-id="102">Session 2</th>
      <th session-id="103">Session 3</th>
      <th session-id="104">Session 4</th>
      <th session-id="105">Session 1</th>
      <th session-id="106">Session 2</th>
      <th session-id="107">Session 3</th>
      <th session-id="108">Session 4</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td student-id="110">Foo</td>
      <td>Bar</td>
      <td>Present</td>
      <td>Absent</td>
      <td>Present</td>
      <td>Present</td>
      <td>Absent</td>
      <td>Present</td>
      <td>Present</td>
      <td>Present</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```